Xerox 6204 - can't access printer's preferences via settings-app
I can't access printer's preferences via settings-app (Windows 10):

But the same works via Control Panel:

I'm printing from one of the CAD app., where I have to set 'media sizes' (they vary from case to case) and the problem is, that printer's preferences inside this CAD app. are being opened via settings-app, which results in an error.
There is no problem when other installed printers are accessing printer's preferences.
I've also tried this on different computers, the same problem on most of them, but on some, where users are permanent for a longer period of time (one computer one user), it works. OS build differs.
I've also found this, but I can't make it work:
https://winclassic.net/thread/1661/ms-settings-uri-redirector
